# Убрать отступ у h1

Tags: html, css

Как убрать этот непонятный отступ у заголовка первого уровня? line-height 100% не помогает. Прилагаю скрин.
http://prntscr.com/b7b4li

Comment: поделитесь кодом, чтобы было проще помочь

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. Как создать [mcve].

Comment: <div class="shop">
        <h1>Магазин</h1>
    </div>

Дело не в padding И margin

Comment: @Анатолий, вся необходимая разметка и стили должны быть непосредственно в вопросе.

Comment: Не вижу отступов на скриншоте. Это нормально?

Answer (score 3):

```
.no_margin {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 0;
}
```

Comment: Там на `h1` уже применён некий класс `no_margin`

Comment: @Виктор, если нечего делать, то лучше найти вопрос, дубликатом которого является этот. Там вроде даже ответ был. А margin и padding вообще не при чём.